# ScriptRegistrar component fails other javascript code to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can someone tell what does the following code (its used in master page) do and why doesn't it let my *View's* javascript to work.

**To make the *View's* javascript work, i need to delete this. But deleting this takes away the telerik control.**

```
@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Manual](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/web-assets-working-with-javascript-web-assets.html#jQuery)

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false) %>
```

Here's [a thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/jquery-selectable-and-html-telerik-scriptregistrar.aspx) in the community forums that explains in a little more detail.

From the thread:

> Generally, if you disable the ScriptRegistrar's jQuery registration, the only requirement is that your own jQuery registration comes before the ScriptRegistrar in the markup